# How to fix if indexes are corrupted in hive metastore. and Partitions table is throwing errors

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, metastore

I am working on a Project where we use CDH embedded postGreSQL.
Few days back we started identifying 2 things.
Tables (hive tables) being created by Sqoop were failing as well as creting dynamic partitioned tables from hive were also failing.

Errors were as follows

1st day:

```
Loading data to table raw_store.user_pdp_visits partition (view_date=null)
Failed with exception MetaException(message:javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Insert of object "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MPartition@67d2b6c" using statemen
t "INSERT INTO "PARTITIONS" ("PART_ID","PART_NAME","TBL_ID","LAST_ACCESS_TIME","CREATE_TIME","SD_ID") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)" failed : ERROR: duplicate key value violates
 unique constraint "PARTITIONS_pkey"
  Detail: Key ("PART_ID")=(481) already exists.
NestedThrowables:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PARTITIONS_pkey"
  Detail: Key ("PART_ID")=(481) already exists.)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
```

Therafter:

```
Moving data to: hdfs://hadoop01.snapdeal.com:8020/tmp/hive-hdfs/hive_2014-05-27_09-00-19_755_4383214683545337621-1/-ext-10000/view_date=2014-05-26
Loading data to table raw_store.user_pdp_visits partition (view_date=null)
Failed with exception MetaException(message:java.lang.RuntimeException: commitTransaction was called but openTransactionCalls = 0. This probably indicates that there ar
e unbalanced calls to openTransaction/commitTransaction)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
```

It will be really great if someone can give some solution for the same.

Comment: What is "CDH embedded PostgreSQL" ? The closest thing I can find [is a Cloudera product](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_embed_pstgrs.html), but they don't call their product "CDH embedded PostgreSQL" and it doesn't actually seem to be embeded PstgreSQL in the usual sense. I think you may need to provide some more details.

Comment: Anyway, this looks like a problem in the tool that's using PostgreSQL, not in PostgreSQL its self. Contact the support for the product you're using.

Comment: Hi Craig, The issue is that we have our metastore configured in PostgreySQL that was installed along with CDH. I am not sure why I was getting this error when trying to generate dynamic partitions with Hive. Please let me know if any real config needs to be looked upon here.